# angular.injector returns new instance of service on every call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I [created a simple plunk that demonstrates the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJKIZ1tcc5k5uzUHaEqa?p=preview).

I need to call a service from outside angular.

When I use

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'MyModule']).get('MyService')
```

I seem to get a new instance every time it is called, or at least behaves as such. In the plunk, notice how the "Increment" button calls the same instance of the service, as opposed to how the "Call Via Injector" works.

I have been banging my head for hours, tried various things, and read many apparently-relevant posts but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I intentionally did that since the call will be coming from outside angular, and in fact from outside JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'MyModule']).get('MyService')
```

to

```
angular.element('[ng-app]').injector().get('MyService').inc();
```

The first one creates an instance of new injector. Every injector in angular has its own instance of services and factories. The second one fetches the existing instance of injector.

Also, to select DOM elements using angular.element, jQuery needs to be included. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DW4icVwWYpbRBw1UAgZ?p=info) is the modified plunk.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is that you are not getting the Injector instance of your scope simply because you placed the callViaInjector button outside of your ng-app.

Though services are singletons in angular, they are only singleton for a specified scope.

Notice that if you place the callViaInjector inside the ng-app you will see that it behaves accordingly.

Comment: I intentionally did that since the call will be coming from outside angular, and in fact from outside JavaScript.

Comment: Each time you call angular.injector(['ng', 'MyModule']).get('MyService') it creates a new scope for itself because it doesn't have one. You cannot expect that everything outside my ng-app is considered to have one scope. So whenever you call that particular line it increments 0 to 1. 0 as I said because it is a new instance of the service in a newly generated scope which is then disposed as soon as that line ends. Why? It just behaves like that, angular cannot determine the scope because you didn't define it.